# How to fix the location of nodes in networkx?

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

How can I fix the location of nodes in networkx? Each frame the cells move because the edges added were different. I'd like to keep all the cells in the same location.

(If you run the code snippet below on `https://colab.research.google.com/` the resulting mp4 file shows how the nodes are moving around. This makes its hard to track the changes over each frame.)

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.animation
import random

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(9, 9, )
pos = {f"{x},{y}":(x,y) for x,y in G.nodes()}
ndxs = [f"{x},{y}" for x,y in G.nodes()]
G=nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
G.add_nodes_from(ndxs)
edges = [
    [(f"{random.randint(0, 8)},{random.randint(0, 8)}", f"{random.randint(0, 8)},{random.randint(0, 8)}") for _ in range(10)]
    for _ in range(20)
]

# Build plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

def update(i):
    ax.clear()
    edgelist = edges[i]

    nx.draw(G, pos, node_color="lightgrey", ax=ax)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(
        G, pos=pos, edgelist=edgelist, 
        arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad=0.5", ax=ax)

    ax.set_title(f"frame {i}")
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=20, interval=250, repeat=True)
ani.save("tmp.mp4")
plt.show()
```

Comment: The nodes stay on the same position, but as the arcs are often outside the boundary, matplotlib zooms out a bit.  You can fix the zooming via the data limits, e.g `ax.set_xlim(-1, 10); ax.set_ylim(-1, 10)` in the `update` function.